# How to enable line break in Bulma css content class within <p></p>

Tags: css, bulma

I'm using Bulma css to create the website and have a textarea input field.
Before saving to the mongoDB, I use the following command to convert the line break \n to 
:

`subject = subject.replace('\n', '<br>')`

Before display the subject into the screen, I use the following code to convert it back: 
`str.replace('<br>', '\n');`
And put the content into a Media content class div.

```
<section className="modal-card-body has-text-black">
  <article className="media has-background-grey-lighter">
    <div className="media-content">
      <div className="content">
        <p>
          {subject}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

However, there is no line break effective, all the text link together.

For exemple, if I input the following text in the textarea:

```
I need to see a doctor.
Please get back to me ASP
```

After saving and converting back, it combine the two lines into one line :

```
I need to see a doctor. Please get back to me ASP
```

Anyone has any suggetion?

Answer (score 1):

After googling and trying for a while, with the following css code, I can enable the line break:

```
.enable-line-break {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following code is available for line break in Bulma CSS:

````
.chat-bubble
{
    white-space: pre !important;
    max-width: 10% !important;
    padding: 2px 9px 2px 9px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```
````